# Fetching Gerrit SSH output in python

Tags: python, ssh, gerrit, plumbum

So I am using plumbum to execute the ssh command against gerrit, but I cant seem to be able to pull the output in as a json dictionary.

```
eg: ssh abc.xyz.com gerrit query --patch-sets --format=json commit:12345678
```

The output of this also dumps the below lines:
    type: abcd
    rowCount: integer
    runTimeMilliseconds: 123
    moreChanges: ABCD

I feel this is also another dictionary.

So, is there anyway to pull the output of the ssh command into a python dictionary?

Ref: https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/cmd-query.html

Comment: Since you seem to be asking specifically about plumbumm I've suggested an edit adding the tag. The answer for that would appear to be [here](https://plumbum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/local_commands.html#input-output-redirection) (but I have no prior exposure), namely the bit `(cat << "hello world\nfoo\nbar\spam" | grep["oo"]) ()` which seems like you should be able to call your command as a function and assign its output to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

The query result can potentially return multiple changes, each of which will be on a separate line, separated by newlines.  The last line of the result is a summary, which includes a hint about whether there are more results (beyond the limit set either server side or by a `limit` option on your query).

In your case, you're querying for a single commit sha1 so you only get one result, but it still includes the summary line.

It should be possible to convert the result to a dict by splitting the output on newlines and converting each line separately, for example:

```
import json
data = ssh["abc.xyz.com",
    "gerrit",
    "query",
    "--patch-sets",
    "--format=JSON",
    "commit:",
    "12345678"]()
data2 = json.loads(data.split()[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

To get an answer in JSON format you need to change the "--format=text" option to "--format=json":

```
ssh abc.xyz.com gerrit query --patch-sets --format=json commit:12345678
```

Comment: My bad. Yes I used that but the issue is that from there on I am unable to store the output into a dict in python as there are two dictionaries which are generated by the output!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got it to work:

```
data = ssh["abc.xyz.com",
    "gerrit",
    "query",
    "--patch-sets",
    "--format=JSON",
    "commit:",
    "12345678"]()

data2 = data[:data.rfind('{')]
```

Is there a better solution?